# React Native send Json.Stringify data to Laravel controller get "Unrecognized token '<'"

Tags: javascript, android, json, laravel-5, react-native

I am trying to post data from react native app by json.stringify to Laravel controller. But getting "**JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'**". I need help how to resolve it. My code are given below:

**js code**

```
fetch(API_URL+'/signup', {
            method: 'post',
            header:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                name: userName,
                email: userEmail,
                password: userPassword
            })

        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) =>{
                alert(response);
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                console.error(error);
            });
```

**Laravel:**

```
public function registerUser() 
    {

        $this->validate(request(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed'
        ]);

        $user = User::create(request(['email', 'name', 'password']));

        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: Try it with this return `return response()->json([
    'state' => 'success'
]);`

Comment: no luck brother :(

Comment: Just give it a try, instead of `body:JSON.stringify(yourObj)`, use this, `body: 'data=' + JSON.stringify(yourObj)` . And then check at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Server return is not a json. You can post the return of the requisition?

Comment: can you explain it a bit. i didn't get you exactly. @Rafael

Answer (score 0):

what the answer above is trying to say is that you are supposed to do

return response()->json("success");

instead of

return "success";

its here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#json-responses

Comment: still getting the error. actually i cant receive the data sending from React Native end.